# Sorting a zipped list - why does 10000000 come before 9?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a zip list - the code I've written so far looks as follows:

```
sorted_list = list(sorted(zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

To my knowledge, this does the same as:

```
unsorted_list = zip(list_a, list_b)
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

My goal is to sort the list according to the values in list_a. This list contains approximately 50000 lines and contains select values from 0 - 100 (no duplicates), before jumping to values such as 10005135 and 40610839.

The problem when I run this code is that it orders numbers as follows 1, 10, 100, 10000000, 40000000, 41, 42, etc.

How can I order my list so that all of these values are truly in ascending order?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are the elements string?

Comment: Yes, the elements in list_a are strings

Comment: Then its sorting correctly. Convert to INT or float types before proceeding to get numerical order.

Comment: Thank you - that was indeed the issue..!

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = list(map(int, list_a))
list_a.sort()
list_b = list(map(int, list_b))
list_b.sort()

sorted_list = list(sorted(zip(list_a, list_b)))
print(sorted_list)
```

First you need to covert your each elements of list into the int and then you need sort it.